# Populating a QListView with data from a std::vector

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a bunch of objects that are stored in a std::vector. Each one of these objects has a name attribute and I would like to display these names in a QListView.

I have read about the ModelView architecture and it sounds like that would suit my needs. I have also read that some people will create a new list of qstrings with the names and populate the list view with that. I would however like to avoid doing this as it introduces data duplication.

What is the best practice for displaying items in a QListView that have their origins in a std::vector or even an array?

Comment: First, you subclass `QAbstractItemModel` and then set it to `QListView` via `QListView::setModel() method`.

Answer (score 0):

QListView needs a model.
In your case QStringListModel can fit your needs if your std::vector is a std::vector but if you're using more complex data you need to write your own model (e.g. by subclassing QAbstractListModel, see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#subclassing).
Your subclass will need to take your std::vector as input and store it or convert it content to any more suited form.

The other option is to use QListWidget instead of QListView and (almost) forget about models. It seems easier for a first try, but as soon as you will want more features (complex data, managing data persistance, etc.) it won't be enough.